# CSS for sidebar in rails app not working on production

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following CSS for my sidebar menu in my rails app.

```
.sidebar-nav-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 60px;
    width: 21.97%;
}
```

In development, it is working exactly as I would like it to, and is staying in the correct position. Here is the view on `localhost`:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuZC9.png]

However, in Production, There is a large white space above the content, and side bar isn't staying fixed.  Here is the view in production:

[image: http://imgur.com/9pQahom]

How can I remedy this situation?

Comment: Can you use a tool like Chrome Dev tools to help diagnose the problem? I have zero experience with rails, so I can't really guess on what's the problem especially since it works as expected in dev.

Comment: So I have looked at the Chrome dev tools, and in production under matched CSS rules it is just not showing up at all.  Here is what it looks like for localhost: http://imgur.com/UP3NyHg.  And here is what it showing up on my production site: http://imgur.com/Mqs4uUo.  I'm at a loss as to why its happening.

Comment: Your content is wrapping so that it appears underneath the `sidebar`. This is most common when you are using some kind of float - and shouldn't occur if your `position: fixed` is actually being applied. Is it possible that you have a stylesheet which isn't being included successfully due to a relative path or something?

Comment: The stylesheet is being loaded though, because everything but this one style is being loaded correctly. I added a work around answer, but But I don't believe it is the rails way.  Also thanks for linking the pictures directly for me, as I wasn't able without 10 rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this by instead using a style in the actual div tag: `<div style="position: fixed">`  Currently this is work around that will be changed once I can figure out why this certain element isn't loading from my css file.